# SQL: Return defined count of records based on categorical column

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks something like as shown below.

I want to return about 5000 random records for each of the three groupings: A, B and C.
The result should be a dataset of 15K different users but I cant get my query to work. Any tips? Note, the table is quite large, hundreds of millions of records so any optimization techniques would be appreciated

Table:

```
Main_ID     USER_ID      email         Groupings
25709422    37609681    11@yah.com      A
25425423    2334        11@yah.co22     A
245545      5235235     11@yah.com212   B
245545      2342342     121@ysh.com123  B
243523      34232       121@#hga.com    C
```

My query below

```
with main as (
    Select main_id, user_id, email, grouping
    from table
),

final as (
    (select WORKSPACE_ID, user_ID, email, MEMBER_COUNT_GROUPINGS, MEMBER_COUNT
from main
WHERE Grouping = 'A'
order by random()
LIMIT 5000
)

UNION ALL
(select  WORKSPACE_ID, user_ID, email, MEMBER_COUNT_GROUPINGS, MEMBER_COUNT
from main
WHERE Groupings = 'B'
order by random()
LIMIT 5000)

UNION ALL
(select  WORKSPACE_ID, user_ID, email, MEMBER_COUNT_GROUPINGS, MEMBER_COUNT
from main
WHERE Groupings = 'C'
order by random()
LIMIT 5000)
)

SELECT * FROM final_final
```

Comment: What's your dbms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function with filter condition in subquery then get rn smaller than 5000.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    select WORKSPACE_ID, 
           user_ID, 
           email, 
           MEMBER_COUNT_GROUPINGS, 
           MEMBER_COUNT,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Grouping ORDER BY random()) rn 
    from main
    WHERE Grouping IN ('A','B','C')
) t1
WHERE rn <= 5000
```

Comment: This returned only 5000 records - was hoping that it would return 15,000 - 5k for A,B,C each :/

Comment: @Blackdynomite No that will return 5000 rows for each `A`,`B`,`C`  due to we add `PARTITION BY Grouping` I don't know what is your dbms this is a sample from sql-sever https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=8457eda5ce311d1d5dfb79791dbfecb2